apache2 webdav ran through docker is empty; even though I can see the files mounted in the docker container
I'm trying to get a webdav server running through docker compose (portainer).
Below is the yaml I'm using
version: '3'

services:
  webdav:
    image: bytemark/webdav
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      AUTH_TYPE: Digest
      USERNAME: 1111
      PASSWORD: 1111
    volumes:
      - /path/to/files:/var/lib/dav

The container is running fine; and I can get into it; however I can't find any of my files.
This seems so simple, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to find the issue.
I can see the files when I run docker exec -it ID /bin/sh and cd into /var/lib/dav... But I can't see them when trying to access through a web browser, I've tried changing permissions chown -R 1000:1000 etc... but with no success.
I know this is probably a very simple issue and is probably a duplicate (although I couldnt find one) this is not my area of expertise, I'm looking to set up a server for zotero for storing and backing up annotated research papers. I'd really appreciate any help.
Thanks.
